# Detect Conflict Periods in Django Forms

Tags: python, django

I have a model that have a `start date` and the number of days. From that I am calculating the STARTING_DATE and the ENDING_DATE of this record.

I want to add a feature in my forms that will check if there is any conflict with the dates

so if there is a model that start in `09-01-2014` the days = 10. I don't want to allow any model to start until `09-11-2014`

I am now passing the parent model to the form. And I need a method for that

```
form = MyForm(request.POST or None, parent=user) # for add
form = MyForm(request.POST or None, parent=user, instance=myModel)
```

I think the best way to do it is to have a list of unAccepted dates. However, this list will be too big if the days value is big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timedelta` is probably your friend here.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

start_date = date.today()
end_date = date(2014, 4, 9)

if start_date - end_date > timedelta(days=10):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```